# Ways to improve an article

Tags: creative-writing

I was told to write an article for a homework assignment. The topic was "How to get good sleep?". I was given the points I had to include, and the word limit was 120-150 words. When I submitted the assignment, my teacher told me the article was not good. What should I keep in mind while writing an article?

Comment: This is very broad.  What kind of article?  How long?  For what audience?  At what level of rigor?

Comment: It was just a homework assignment on how to get good sleep. I was given the points I had to include and the word limit was 120-150 words.

Comment: I would start by talking with the reader who critiqued my work about what she found deficient.

Comment: Alright. I will ask my teacher the flaws in it

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do so, but without any more or clearer feedback, it is hard to say. Perhaps you can provide more insight.

- Make sure your grammar and syntax are correct
- Work with facts (and provide impartial sources)
- Make sure your article is not only a collection of your thoughts and opinions
- Paragraphs
- Essay format: intro, development, conclusion
- Since this is school, make sure you do not go against your teacher's views and beliefs (that's a big one, nothing I said or wrote at school ever meant anything to me, it was just to please the teachers).

Those are simple ideas.

Comment: Any more tips because I included all those in my article but my teacher still said that it isn't good. I don't know if it's on a whole or compared to my previous writing works because I am kinda the writer of the class. So any more tips or something I should take care of.

Comment: Ask the teacher for more feedback and ways to improve your article. Saying "this sucks" without any more details means very little and is not conducive to you improving your writing. Don't take it personal, it is a critique of your work and use that to improve.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your patience. I will always keep in mind the tips you have given me. Of course I won't take it personal, it would be silly. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Another way to improve your article is peer editing. Ask your friend or family to take a look at your article and see if you can improve on anything.

Answer (score 1):

General Tips to help Improve Article Writing Skills.

**1. Start up.**

Don’t worry about the length of your article besides this you should keep in mind that you’re writing this article for developing your skills of writing which can help you many people in future to develop the same for themselves.

“The fewer words you use, the better.”

**2.Write Early in the  morning.**

Morning time allows them to write fresh stuffs.

**3.Be a Good Reader**

This is the most mandatory thing for the one who wants to build their  career in Writing  or Blogging.

**4.Be Simple.**

For generating good traffic on your contents, your way of writing should be simple enough. For that express your views in a simple and appropriate way. This will help visitors or readers in a good manner.

**5.Complete your articles in various stages.**

There are stages to follow while you’re writing on a single topic. Be sure these all stages needs some specific time. For that, you need to make your schedule for following stages. And then it will become a healthy content for sure.

**6.Write in a Distraction Free Location.**

**7.Go smoothly.**

To create better and attractive content try not to edit while you are creating your article – just go with the flow of your thoughts.

**8.Research well before Writing.**

Before you start, do very thorough research on the particular topic on which you are going to write.

and Lastly , As they say, “Practice makes a man perfect,”  If you want to be a good writer you must make a habit of regularly writing .

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the 5th point? And my problem is that I make it too big if I try to go with the flow. Last time I was told to write a 150 word story I made it up as long as 2 pages.

Comment: Can follow : https://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-write-articles-for-your-readers.html

Answer (score 0):

When writing a short informative article (125 words) you have to get to the point fairly early. You don't need a multiple-line introduction. Use one sentence to set the topic. In your case that would be improving sleep quality.

Before starting to write do your research properly. First you would start of would with a brainstorm. How do I sleep? I go to bed too late. I use a smartphone before going to bed (very hot topic at the moment). How do other people sleep? My mom snores. She is often tired. Just use some keywords, about 12 brainstorm words should be enough for producing an article of 120 words.

- sleep hygiene, smartphone, snoring, matras hardness, pillow, blood flow, noise, light, temperature, therapies, stress, relaxation techniques..

Then find research articles. Two would be enough, but to impress your teacher use about 5 articles.

Use scientific terminology. When introducing a new concept, it is best to *italicize* the word (e.g. "To improve sleep quality psychologists suggest to maintain a healthy *sleep hygiene*.")

Furthermore, using an acronym is a popular technique to remind people of the steps toward a health outcome. But you may not have enough words for that.

- **S**timulus balancing: light, noise, temperature
- **L**eave your smartphone in an other room
- **E**at light before going to bed.
- **E**valuate tasks done in a diary
- **P**rioritize important tasks in the morning

Give a one-sentence conclusion.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely keep these in mind when I am writing an article the next time. That helped me a lot. Can we use quotes in an article? I mean, not in this one but some articles like women reform or freedom or something like that?